# Fastest JDBC driver for SQL Server

Tags: gratis, sql-server, jdbc

What is the **fastest** [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) for [Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)?
Especially for SELECT operations with simple WHERE clauses, but also for INSERT and UPDATE operations.

It must also be reliable, free to use, and ideally open source.
It is for use within [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat), if that matters. Memory usage is not a problem.

*Both personal experiences and benchmarks welcome.*

Answer (score 1):

[jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) is an open source JDBC implementation for Microsoft SQL Server.

This benchmarks shows jTDS as faster for many tests, and in particular more than twice as fast as competitors for the "ResultSetReadAllRows" test:

[image: jtds benchmark]

The benchmark has been made by jTDS, so I am not sure how reliable it is, though. Other benchmarks would be welcome.

Drawbacks: jTDS is hosted on SourceForge and the last release was in 2013, with the last commit in November 2014.

Comment: I have used jTDS in several projects and it was faster than the Microsoft implementation at the time (2014) and less buggy. However, Microsoft's JDBC driver is now open source on GitHub and it may be worth checking out as it is actively developed and supported with additional features like Windows Integrated Authentication and Distributed Transactions